# TYPO3 hmenu disable one link

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have menu with 2 level. All links are clickable but I want to disable 1 link. This link is being used for opening submenu

```
         <li class="sub-link"><a href="#">link1</a>
            <ul id="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#">sublink</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">sublink2</a></li>
            </ul> <!-- sub-menu -->
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link5</a></li>
```

I want to disable link 1. I have such typoscript:

```
lib.menu.main  = HMENU
lib.menu.main {
    special = list
    special.value =  22,154,88
    alwaysActivePIDlist = 22
    1 = TMENU
    1.NO = 1          
    1.wrap = <ul>|</ul>
    1.NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
    1.IFSUB=1
    1.IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="sub-link">|</li>
    2 < .1
    2.wrap = <ul id="sub-menu">|</ul>
    2.NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
}
```

How I can decide this problem?

Comment: how you mean you want to disable it? It should just open the submenu and not link to a page?

Comment: yes, if you hover link, submenu should be shown, but if you click by link, action is not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i got two possibilities for you to solve this problem:

The first one is to read the Typo3-Documentation and look up for "optionSplit" and "doNotLinkIt"-options. They should help you solving your problem within typoscript.

The other is to solve it using Javascript/JQuery. You could select the (in your example above) FIRST item of the menu and replace the link with whatever you want.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu a').first().attr('href', '#');
});
```

I made you a fiddle with the whole example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/bdrsssv7/

---

Make sure you do not insert the Javascript in the HTML template because it will not be available on pages with other html-templates then.
Just do a js-file and insert it via typoscript like this:

```
page.includeJS.file1 = fileadmin/yourTemplateLocation/yourFile.js
```

I hope one of the two solutions i mentioned could help you

Answer (score 2):

Excluding a specific PID (18) from the menu in Typoscript:

```
lib.menu = HMENU
lib.menu {
    special = rootline
    special.range = 2,0
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        NO {
            allWrap = <li> | </li>
            doNotLinkIt.override = 1
            doNotLinkIt.override.if {
                value = 18
                equals.field = uid
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OR exclude multiple specific PIDs (18,19,20) from the menu

```
lib.menu.1.NO.doNotLinkIt.override.if {
    value = 18,19,20
    isInList.field = uid
}
```

Comment: The better solution, than what is marked as the answer. Although all three proposals work in the end.